# 8080 Assembly Clarification

Tags: assembly, disassembly, intel-8080

I am making a disassembler for 8080 assembly. Correct me if I'm wrong:
All I have to do is read the binary byte by byte, translating each byte into a command.
Or are there conditions which would increase the length of the command (in the binary).

Comment: Well, there are operands in there, too (like memory addresses, or immediate values).

Comment: Opcodes are 1 byte but the whole instruction may be more than that if it needs additional operands. You will need an instruction set reference anyway, so why not just look at one?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you have a dos tag?  did you mean 8088 and not 8080?

In either case no, absolutely not you cannot just go linearly one byte at a time.  Both of those instruction sets are variable length instructions.  You have to look at how they boot, vector table or entry address, and then you have to follow the possible execution paths.

From the reset entry point you disassemble linearly until you reach a branch conditional or unconditional, this provides you with two more entry points to linearly disassemble from.  An unconditional branch ends disassembly of a section.

You should keep track of which bytes are opcodes and which bytes are additional data for those opcodes.  If you have the bytes i j k l m  and i, k and l are opcodes, or lets say first bytes of an instruction and j and m are secondary bytes.  Then if somewhere else you find a branch to the address where the k byte lives, then that is okay, but if you find a branch to the byte where j lives either that is a clever hacker or you have a problem.  And wouldnt be surprised from time to time if that problem was intentional to prevent disassembly.  Compiler generated code often wont have this problem, but hand assembly (machine code) might (for the unintended cases) and the further back in time you go the more likey to run across hand coded assembly/machine code.

Answer (score 3):

Compared to the 8086, the 8080's instruction set is very simple when it comes to instruction length. There are only three cases:

1. 1-byte instructions: for instance, `XRA A`.
2. 1-byte instructions followed by 1 byte of data: for instance, `MVI A,0`.
3. 1-byte instructions followed by 2 bytes of data: for instance, `LXI B,0`.

This makes a disassembler really easy. In fact this is how I learned 8080 assembly language generally: by disassembling the built-in Basic interpreter on my computer (using a disassembler written in Basic with lots of PEEK commands) and using the knowledge to build a BIOS so as to be able to install CP/M.

dwelch is right that it is possible for code to jump into the middle of an instruction. The Microsoft Basic interpreter used precisely this trick, as follows:

```
01 2E 00
01 2E 01
01 2E 02
... code using the value of L
```

Calling byte offset 01 in this sequence would execute `2E 00`, which is `MVI L,0`, which sets register L to zero. There then follow two `LXI B` instructions, setting register BC to 012E and 022E, which is pointless (and the value is ignored).

Calling byte offset 04 in this sequence would execute `2E 01`, which is `MVI L,1`, which sets register L to 1. There then follows one `LXI B` instruction, setting register BC to 022E, which is pointless (and the value is ignored).

Calling byte offset 07 in this sequence would execute `2E 02`, which is `MVI L,2`, which sets register L to 2.

The bottom line is that at offset 09, we end up with L=0 if offset 01 was called, L=1 if offset 04 was called, or L=2 if offset 07 was called. Each call takes only 3 bytes (`CD xxx xx`), and the overhead of setting those different L-values is only 9 bytes.

Without this cleverness, either 15 bytes would have had to be used, to set up L (2 bytes) and jump to the start of whatever routine is using L (3 bytes), or L would have had to be set up by the caller, meaning that each call to the routine would have taken 5 bytes (2 to set up L, 3 to make the call) rather than 3.

Part of the fun of 8080 disassembly is discovering these tricks!